# List of dictionaries from pairs in list

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Looking for a way to transform a list of coordinates into pairs of dictionaries, i.e if:

```
l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

I want to create a list of dictionaries:

```
output = [{'x': 1, 'y': 2}, {'x': 3, 'y': 4}, ... ]
```

Any ideas on how to do this "pythonically"?

Comment: Is the list always going to contain sequential numbers?

Comment: @Asad - not at all, I just didn't want to give a complex example.

Comment: You probably want `{'x': 1, 'y': 2}` instead of `{x: 1, y: 2}`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
output = [{'x': l[i], 'y': l[i+1]} for i in range(0, len(l), 2)]
```

Or alternatively:

```
output = [{'x': x, 'y': y} for x, y in zip(*[iter(l)]*2)]
```

This method of grouping items from a list comes straight from the [`zip()` documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip).

Comment: I don't get why anyone would use Python and still insist on iterating by index. It's crazy. The language is specifically designed so you don't have to do so, and functions badly when you do.

Answer (score 10):

The typical way is with the ["grouper"](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#recipes) recipe:

```
from itertools import izip
def grouper(iterable,n):
    return izip(*[iter(iterable)]*n)

output = [{'x':a,'y':b} for a,b in grouper(l,2)]
```

The advantage here is that it will work with *any iterable*.  The iterable does not need to be indexable or anything like that...

Comment: This is very nice, but I think I prefer the one-liners for the application at hand.

Comment: @nbubis -- you *can* inline the `grouper` function without any real problem.  It just becomes less clear when reading it.

Comment: One-liners that hurt readability are a terrible idea. This is, by far, the best answer.

Comment: NB in Python 3 this recipe would use the built-in `zip`, which works like `izip` used to.

Answer (score 4):

You can do:

```
>>> mylist = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
>>> [{'x': x, 'y': y} for x, y in zip(mylist[::2], mylist[1::2])]
[{'y': 2, 'x': 1}, {'y': 4, 'x': 3}, {'y': 6, 'x': 5}, {'y': 8, 'x': 7}]
```

Note that dictionaries are unordered so `{'y': 2, 'x': 1}` is the same as `{'x': 1, 'y': 2}`. This makes use of Python's built-in [`zip()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) function.

Answer (score 2):

here's another way

```
>>> from itertools import izip
>>> l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
>>> l = iter(l)
>>> [dict(x=x, y=y) for (x, y) in izip(l, l)]                                   
[{'y': 2, 'x': 1}, {'y': 4, 'x': 3}, {'y': 6, 'x': 5}, {'y': 8, 'x': 7}]
```

Or, as Lattyware suggests

```
 >>> [{'x':x, 'y':y} for (x, y) in izip(l, l)]
 [{'y': 2, 'x': 1}, {'y': 4, 'x': 3}, {'y': 6, 'x': 5}, {'y': 8, 'x': 7}]
```

Comment: Using the `dict()` built-in instead of a literal is both less readable and [slower](http://doughellmann.com/2012/11/the-performance-impact-of-using-dict-instead-of-in-cpython-2-7-2.html).

Answer (score 2):

I believe a `namedtuple` would be more suited to this job than a dictionary. (Using [`itertools` grouper](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#recipes) recipe like @mgilson)

```
>>> from collections import namedtuple
>>> from itertools import izip
>>> Point = namedtuple('Point', ('x', 'y'))
>>> def grouper(iterable,n):
        return izip(*[iter(iterable)]*n)

>>> nums = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
>>> [Point(x, y) for x, y in grouper(nums, 2)]
[Point(x=1, y=2), Point(x=3, y=4), Point(x=5, y=6), Point(x=7, y=8)]
```

Comment: +1. It's worth noting that I believe `namedtuple`s also have an `asdict()` method that gives back an (OrderedDict?) dict with the names to the values.